# How to redirect to another application Single Sign On Identity Server 4 and logout

Tags: identityserver4

I have an application A and an application B both of which are Asp.Net MVC Core 2.2 which should behave as if they are a single application to the end user; I'm using SSO in Identity Server; and in order to share claims between them I have given them the same Authentication Cookie name, Application name and access to a shared data protection key location as per the instructions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-2.2

If I login to A and then Redirect to B I can see the claims as expected shared between the applications; however if I then logout from B the logoutId which is generated and sent to the Identity Server 4 has no knowledge of B.

If I give a different name for the Authentication Cookie then I cannot share the claims but after redirecting to B and then logout from B the logoutId which is generated works correctly.

If after redirecting to B then waiting for the login session to timeout and re-authenticating then logout the logout of B works correctly; and the logoutId which is generated and sent to Identity Server 4 has knowledge of both A and B.

I believe this is because after redirecting to B when the Authorize attribute triggers a check that the user is Authenticated; which the user is in Application A and this is 'mistaken' for being already Authenticated in B; as this is a SSO there is no reason to authenticate in B as if authentication was checked with the Identity Server 4 then the user would be authenticated; however since the authentication is not checked the knowledge that the user has redirected to B is not stored in the shared authentication cookie and thus on Sign-out the Identity Server 4 does not receive the correct logoutId.

What can I do to force Identity Server 4 to be notified and thus update the Shared Cookie after the redirect to Application B?

Comment: Thanks to Vidmantas Blazevicius; I'm accepting their answer as I believe the issue is that the article linked above is describing how to create SSO like behaviour if you don't have an authentication server which supports this natively - which I do in Identity Server 4; and I would recommend that claims are not used to share information between applications that you need to keep for any length of time in multiple applications as this will most likely lead to situations in which information goes missing during re-authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use shared cookies between your Angular apps to achieve SSO behavior. Neither you should share claims between those apps. In OAuth, the SSO is achieved by having a single authority uri (your Identity Server 4) that all your domain apps use to authenticate users, meaning that once user goes to application `A` and is redirected to login and completes login flow, the cookie is left on the on your Identity Server 4 app, and then once you redirect your application `B` it will see that it's not authenticated and redirect to the Identity Server 4 which will then use the cookie and automatically log the user in (can even skip consent page optionally).

Single sign out is a bit more difficult and is achieved by using `SignOutIFrame` on your Identity Server 4. In a nutshell, the idea is that once you initiate the logout flow from one of your apps, after the user successfully logs out from the Identity Server 4 app, the rendering of this `SignOutIFrame` causes all other clients to optionally participate in the logout flow and clear the session, etc. for a given user. More info can be found [here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/signout.html).

Comment: Ok - the applications are not Angular they are MVC (question edited to clarify); I'm not sharing the claims to enable an SSO scenario I'm sharing the claims because the applications should behave as a single application (Application B is never browsed to directly it's redirected from Application A) if I can get Application B to be aware that it has been activated during redirect then the SSO sign-out does work correctly - i.e. I have the SignOutIFrame in identity server 4 and the database configured correctly with the FrontEndChannel endpoint of the Signout of each application.

Comment: From the article that is linked it is showing how to share an authentication cookie between two applications; but I think it should say that is not recommended for information that is long lived; as the information in the claims which is being shared is limited to the time the principle is valid; once the principle is rejected then any claim information added by the first application will be lost and only the claims which are added by the identity server will be restored - I think that is what you are saying in your answer if you agree please update it and I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: To be honest, you should not follow anything in that article about cookie sharing, because if you use identity server and you have 2 applications as 2 different oauth clients then you don’t need cookie sharing at all.